# Using slick.js carousel and lazy loader to display a fullscreen image carousel

Tags: jquery, background-image, lazy-loading, background-size, slick.js

I'm using slick.js carousel with the inbuilt lazy loading functionality to display a fullscreen image gallery. The one problem I have is that lazy loader only displays using an img tag so I can't apply background-size:cover to it and I don't want to overkill it by using a js plugin to make it fullscreen. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: If you provide some code [and a fiddle], I could try to help you.

Comment: Thanks @BishopBarber . Here's a jsbin http://jsbin.com/yijiyuyekidu/1/edit?html,css,js,output I hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

You really should be using the `img` tag. You can not use the lazy loading on `div` tags, since slick only adds the lazy loading effect to `img` tags having a `data-lazy` attribute set. From the [plugin's source](https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/blob/4f8adffddb949cddb8a447f18dc3ccb182c7ac3e/slick/slick.js):

```
$('img[data-lazy]', _.$slider).not('[src]').addClass('slick-loading');
```

All you need to do is to put each of your `img` tags in a `div` tag:

```
<div class="a-slide">
    <img data-lazy="http://lorempixel.com/800/800/animals/"/>
</div>
```

Then, just as you did, set your `html`, `body` and `div` tags height and width to 100%. But do not forget to put your `img` tags heght and width to 100% too, since now you have them. Besides, you don't even need `background-size:cover`. However, if you want your images to not lose too much of their quality, use `object-fit: cover;` on them. Your css would be similar to this:

```css
html{
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}

body{
    height: inherit;
    width: inherit;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.a-slide{
    height: inherit;
    width: inherit;
}

.a-slide img {
    height: inherit;
    width: inherit;
    object-fit: cover; /* This is a new property that can be used on img tags */
}
```

Then call the slick plugin as you must with the `lazyLoad` setting set to `ondemand` or `progressive`:

```
$('.lazy-slick').slick({
    lazyLoad: 'ondemand'
});
```

[Working demo](http://jsbin.com/wucuwutepa/1)

If that's not exactly the expected behaviour, don't hesitate to say.

Comment: Yeah that's exactly what I'm after @BishopBarber. However by using width and height 100% on an img tags skews the image quite heavily hence why I wanted to use background-size: cover as that keep everything in perspective regardless of browser dimensions. Any ideas on how to solve this? And thanks again for helping!

Comment: @FrazerFindlater `object-fit: cover;` on your `img` tags is your best bet with only css. See my edit

Comment: Yeah I thought about using that but I don't think IE9+ handles it too well. Are there any lightweight Jquery fullscreen plugins that you know of? I think I might have to compromise.

Comment: @FrazerFindlater I tried it in IE8 and the full screen images seems to work pretty well.